# How can I create a cron job which runs on a specific date and time in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-schedule

In my app every user will have a particular deliverydate when they buy a subscription so once they buy the subscription we will show an option saying "Remind me after" for reminding few things exactly 24 hours before the delivery date (A button on react frontend which calls remindmeafter API on nodejs)and I want to create a cron job for this use case.

**So Far Here are my trials:**

1. Initially I have tried node-schedule as they are supporting specific date and time based cron job and here is my code for the same.

```js
const date = new Date(moment(subcriptiondata.deliveryDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').subtract(1, 'days').subtract(5, 'hours').add(30, 'seconds').tz('America/Toronto'))

const job = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function() {

  ejs.renderFile(emailUser, {
    data: MailObj
  }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.info('ERROR::::while sending reminder' + err);
    }
    emailApi.sendEmailApi(
      `Reminder `,
      'Reminder',
      results,
      subcriptiondata.email,
      'Mail sent failure',
      'Mail sent successfully',
      process.env.EMAIL_SENDER
    );
  });

})
```

However I've then found on their documentation that node-schedule doesn't persist the data on server restart and which isn't suitable for my app.

2. I have then tried it using cron module and as per their documentation they also support date-based cron job and here is my code for it :

```js
const date = new Date(moment(subcriptiondata.deliveryDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').subtract(1, 'days').subtract(5, 'hours').add(30, 'seconds').tz('America/Toronto'))

const job = new CronJob(date, function() {

  ejs.renderFile(emailUser, {
    data: MailObj
  }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      logger.info('ERROR::::while sending reminder' + err);
    }
    emailApi.sendEmailApi(
      `Scheduled Reminder `,
      'Scheduled Reminder',
      results,
      subcriptiondata.email,
      'Mail sent failure',
      'Mail sent successfully',
      process.env.EMAIL_SENDER
    );
  });

}, null, true, 'America/Toronto');
```

I have deployed and tried both the codes however none of them are working as I'm not receiving any emails for the scheduled date.It would be great if someone here can help me with this on what I'm doing wrong here and I would prefer the second one i.e, using cron module as it persists server restarts.

Update: I have tried with every 5 mins trigger an email instead of specific date and I did received emails in this case.

Comment: Note that moment.js has been depreciated for 2 years and is not recommend for new designs. See [Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for alternatives.

Comment: To have reminders persist you need to store the reminder requests in a database. I recommend two steps: **1.** when receiving the reminder request, your node app stores it with timestamp in the database. **2.** create a standalone node script that runs, say, hourly by a unix cron job. That script reads the unprocessed reminder requests, and if 24h have passed, sends the email, and updates the record in the database as processed

Comment: Have you tried sending an unscheduled email to confirm that your code is configured correctly to send emails?  Have you listed the crons to ensure that your code is actually creating new ones?  Please update the question to include basic debugging information.

Comment: @Yogi Yes I did and I have received the emails when I made the cron job run every 5 mins once I hit the api

Comment: @PeterThoeny I will check on your suggestion .however, It would be great If I can know why a cron job isnt running through the above mentioned approach because cron did even persisted the cronjob even when I restarted the server when testing with every 1 min ,Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the node.js CronJob

Comment: After researching this more, I don't think either of your solutions persist the data. Both Node Scheduler and Node Cron seem to use timers rather than creating native cron jobs.  If you want the data to persist between restarts then  you'd need to store and reload the jobs (a simple json file would be enough).  Or you could look at other alternatives like [cronbee](https://github.com/atmajs/cronbee)

Comment: A good solution for jobs and cronjobs in nodejs is the bull package.https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull. But you need a redis server for this. A more lightweight solution can be https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron. However you need to persist the data for the jobs in a database.

Comment: sure I'll try these methods once,thanks!